# zeppelin web frontend error with angular

Tags: angularjs, apache-zeppelin

I am a beginner to zeppelin.  Today i tried to install zeppelin on my computer with command :

**mvn clean install -Pspark-1.5.1 -Dhadoop.version=2.3.0-cdh5.0.2 -Phadoop-2.3 -DskipTests**

I got an error of "**karma:unit**" test doesn't pass so i added "`--force`" to the maven goal of grunt at "`zeppelin-web/pom.xml`" file. After that, I did pass mvn install command with the following result。

However， when I visiting the index page of zeppelin-web I got an blank page with some javascript errors. It shows via the console of the browser developer tools of error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module zeppelinWebApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module angular.filter due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'angular.filter' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/nomod?p0=angular.filter
    at http://172.21.4.227:8080/scripts/vendor.js:36:380
    at http://172.21.4.227:8080/scripts/vendor.js:36:9937
```

When i try the same thing at other computer, I got following errors:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module zeppelinWebApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngRoute due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngRoute' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/nomod?p0=ngRoute
    at http://172.20.36.248:12048/scripts/vendor.js:36:380
    at http://172.20.36.248:12048/scripts/vendor.js:36:9937
```

I try every means to solve it but with little knowledge of frontend skills, I have no ideas what to do. Could anyone help me with it ? Thanks very much.

Following is the mvn result:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Zeppelin ........................................... SUCCESS [ 17.732 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Interpreter .............................. SUCCESS [ 18.971 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Zengine .................................. SUCCESS [  9.105 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Spark dependencies ....................... SUCCESS [ 34.072 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Spark .................................... SUCCESS [ 37.429 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Markdown interpreter ..................... SUCCESS [  2.069 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Angular interpreter ...................... SUCCESS [  1.903 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Shell interpreter ........................ SUCCESS [  1.943 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Hive interpreter ......................... SUCCESS [  5.718 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Apache Phoenix Interpreter ............... SUCCESS [  7.575 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: PostgreSQL interpreter ................... SUCCESS [  3.014 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Tajo interpreter ......................... SUCCESS [  2.681 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Flink .................................... SUCCESS [ 10.524 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Apache Ignite interpreter ................ SUCCESS [  4.666 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Kylin interpreter ........................ SUCCESS [  2.621 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Lens interpreter ......................... SUCCESS [  6.013 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Cassandra ................................ SUCCESS [01:05 min]
[INFO] Zeppelin: web Application .......................... SUCCESS [02:26 min]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Server ................................... SUCCESS [ 21.470 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Packaging distribution ................... SUCCESS [  1.740 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 06:41 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-11-14T21:04:28+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 158M/544M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The requested profile "spark-1.5.1" could not be activated because it does not exist.
```

Answer (score 0):

try "mvn clean package -DskipTests"